# Automate clicking on JavaScript link with Selenium

Tags: dom, xpath, selenium, automation, selenium-ide

I am trying to automate a click to page 2 of a database that runs asynchronously on a webpage. When using the Xpath:

```
//id('standardView')/x:div[3]/x:div[3]/x:a[1]
```

I get the following error:

```
[error] Invalid xpath [2]: //id('rightMenu')/x:div[3]/x:div[3]/x:a[1]
```

So I tried using DOM to find its path, and the below code brings up the actual link being pushed when run with Firebug...

```
   main = document.getElementById("rightMenu"); mainCont = main.contentDocument;
   paging = mainCont.getElementsByTagName("a"); pageTwo = paging[0];
```

Firebug will show:

```
<a href="javascript:chgPage(2);">
```

but Selenium is throwing this error:

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-
core/scripts/selenium-api.js, lineNumber -> 2535, columnNumber -> 45
```

And just plain 'ol recording the action isn't picking up that the button is being pressed. I can't seem to find a workaround solution. Any insight, my friends?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinda strange xpath. Try to use `//*[@id='standardView']/div[3]/div[3]/a[1]`

But try to use selectors without indexes and as short as possible

`//a[@href='javascript:chgPage(2);']`

or

`//*[@id='standardView']//a[@href='javascript:chgPage(2);']`

These ones can work as well (if they're unique, check this with firepath plugin for firebug)

Comment: Thanks, Alexander! I used

    //a[@href='javascript:chgPage(2);']

and it worked perfectly.